# Android Orientation for Buttons click action

Tags: android

I had 3 buttons in my activity and i clicked Button-2 now focus is on Button-2 when i changed the orientation then the focus should be on Button-2 but the focus is lost on Button-2 so how to handle this situation in android.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. When you rotate your device all views in Activity will destroy, that is why your button loses a focus. If you want to restore focus on button2 you need to do it on your own.